# What is the origin (languague derived from) of NULL?

Tags: language-agnostic, null, terminology

A bit off topic but what is the origin behind NULL?

I sent an email to a French speaking customer containing "thank you for bringing in your  NULL 'item'".

Apparently in French, NULL (NUL) translates to:

nul, nulle /nyl/

I. adjective

(familiar) [personne] hopeless, useless;

[travail, étude] worthless;

[film, roman] trashy (colloquial);

Oops, I insulted them.  Perhaps of French origin?

Comment: I'd be offended by your failed mail-merge code whether I spoke French or not ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Etymology

From Middle French *nul*, from Latin *nullus*.

### Noun

**null** (plural **nulls**)

1. A non-existent or empty value or set of values.
2. Zero quantity of expressions; nothing.
3. (computing) the ASCII or Unicode character (␀), represented by a zero value, that indicates no character and is sometimes used as a string terminator.
4. (computing) the attribute of an entity that has no valid value.

> Since no date of birth was entered for
>   the patient, his age is null.

### Adjective

**null** (comparative **more null**, superlative **most null**)

1. Having no legal validity, "null and void"
2. insignificant
3. absent or non-existent
4. (mathematics) of the null set
5. (mathematics) of or comprising a value of precisely zero
6. (genetics, of a mutation) causing a complete loss of gene function, amorphic.

Source: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/null).

Apparently Tony Hoare (of quicksort fame) introduced the concept of null values in computing. He later called that his "[billion-dollar mistake](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)" referring to the damage bugs involving null pointers have caused over the decades.

Answer (score 1):

From the Latin [Nullus](http://mymemory.translated.net/t/Latin/English/de%20nullo) == "Nothing"

In french, Nul, mainly means equal to zero, none existent, and by familiar extension, of little importance, or worthless.

Answer (score 1):

"Null" is an English word. According to my dictionary it means invalid, non-existant, or without character or expression. Also according to my dictionary (Oxford dictionary of Current English) it derives from Latin, which could mean it got to English by way of French.

Answer (score 1):

I'm french, "Nul" is widely used as useless or worthless.

If your customer is used to reading your messages in english, it should be OK (especially if he works in IT domain).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it was a French translated email and they have no IT background, but it was a light-hearted complain :)

Comment: What was exactly your message (in french)?